# CPU-eating query

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

My QA database has some troubling CPU spikes.  I applied a recommended patch for SQL Server 2017, some improvement but not much. I ran a report on the highest CPU use per query, and there's one way out in front with a total time of 70 seconds (not *ms*, over a minute!). Since it's just a [select from a single table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BnkV.png), am I right to assume the awkward date conversion is probably the culprit?  For all I know it repeats the conversion for every row in the table.

```
SELECT 
   [XREF_lib_IMPL].[..] 
FROM [XREF_LIB_IMPL] 
WHERE [XREF_LIB_IMPL].[FK.XREF_LIB_IMPL]=@1 
  AND CONVERT([varchar](50).[XREF_LIB_IMPL].[DATE_EXPIRED].(120))=@
```

Comment: Run the query in SSMS with `Include Execution Plan` enabled, should pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: [Getting help with a slow query](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/). It could be your convert. It could be blocking. It could be a bunch of other resource contention. It could be paralellization. It could be... (anything)

Comment: That `Convert` isn't doing you any favors, though - it renders that element of the `Where` clause non-SARG-able.  If `Date_Expired` is a date, you should convert whatever parameter that is to a date and compare directly.  Also make sure your indices and statistics are fresh.